# Ignore "Local NPM module not found" warning in Grunt

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I'm using **matchdep** to read dependencies from my `package.json` file into `grunt`.

```
require('matchdep').filterAll('grunt-*').forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
```

I have my dependencies split between `dependencies` (for everyone) and `devDependencies` (for front-end developers.)

Our back-end devs will run the following to get a build of the static assets without requiring jasmine, phantomJS, etc (things that will be run by front-end devs and the CI server)

```
$ npm install --production
$ grunt build
```

However, when using the `--production` build, `grunt.loadNpmTasks()` will emit a warning for any missing packages.

```
>> Local Npm module "grunt-contrib-watch" not found. Is it installed?
```

**Is there a way to supress this warning?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CLI flags to pass options into grunt. For consistency, I am using a `--production` flag, just as I do with npm.

So, from the CLI:

```
$ grunt build --production
```

And then in the Gruntfile:

```
var dependencies;

// test for the production flag
if (grunt.option('production')) {
    // scan dependencies but ignore dev
    dependencies = require('matchdep').filter('grunt-*');
} else {
    // scan all dependencies
    dependencies = require('matchdep').filterAll('grunt-*');
}

// load only relevant dependencies
dependencies.forEach(grunt.loadNpmTasks);
```

This is done at the top of the module before any custom tasks are registered.

Answer (score 1):

You have to question why your "back-end devs" would have to actually build your package - put otherwise, why do they need grunt but NOT devDependencies. This is kind of backwards (requiring *users* to build your package is certainly an anti-pattern).

That being said, using matchdep, you can / should use:

- `require('matchdep').filter` inside your "production" target
- `require('matchdep').filterAll` inside your "development" target

Certainly, that would require you to specialize your `grunt build` (eg: have `grunt builddev` and `grunt buildproduction` - or maybe use environment variables) - but again, see above...

Comment: Ignoring project politics for a moment, this is for using grunt as a task runner for compiling LESS and running jasmine tests in Java web-app, so back-end devs are just that: Java developers. The "users" are the front-end devs who actually need all that stuff; the Java devs just need compiled assets, which I'm not going to check into source control for obvious reasons. In any case, the hint about environment variables got me on the right path, so I can upvote but not accept.

Comment: Happy you devised a solution from the suggestion ;) - now - I don't want to be heavy, but look at bootstrap (or event bower or grunt, or many others): the build result *is* committed (into dist)... Best regards.

Comment: I think that makes sense for when your package has real users; mine is a team of 5 devs, and we're using SVN. Everything I'm doing is to avoid SVN hassle.

Comment: I feel you! All the best.